# Everytime I Move My Mouse A Snapshot of Active Applications Pops Up on Screen

Tags: windows, windows-10, display, mouse

I'm using Windows 10 and when I move my mouse a list of active applications pop up - blocking the active window.

Please see
[image: screenshot].

As you can see in the image above a snapshot of all active applications is displayed (surrounded by a black box border) whenever I move the mouse. For example, I could be using Google Chrome and move mouse on a slant (either up or down) and the black box with snapshot of every active application appears. In order for me to dismiss it I need to click outside the black border. I don't know what activates this box and how to get rid of it.

It's very annoying because I almost can't move my mouse without this box popping up.

Any idea how to get rid of this?

Thanks

Comment: @DavidPostill I edited the question. What other details are you interested in ?

Comment: I cannot see any snapshot surrounded by a black box in your image. Are you referring to the task manager window?

Comment: Ah. I get it. The huge black box. Looks like a screen snap shot.

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks for reopening! Ya. That huge black box. If I have 5 applications opened it will show all 5 in that box. It's annoying because it pops up almost every time I move the mouse.

Comment: It looks a lot like the alt-tab (task switcher) dialog.

Comment: @LPChip Just hit alt-tab on my computer and the same dialog appears. So yes it is the same except that it happens whenever I move my mouse..

Comment: Its not normal behavior. Does it happen with other mouse? Do you have software installed that does keypresses? have you tried scanning for viruses and malware, because it seems like something is doing alt-tab.

Comment: @LPChip I'm using MX Master mouse from Logitech. This used to happen on my old laptop. I just built myself a new PC and have almost no 3rd party software installed on it so I don't think it is malware. Maybe something to do with the mouse?

Comment: it can be a macro on the mouse, yes.

Comment: @LPChip hmm.. how would I know? I never programmed the mouse.. never added any macros..

Comment: You can try a different mouse to rule out the mouse, and try that mouse on another computer to confirm its the mouse.

Comment: I suspect you are hitting a hidden "gesture" button on your mouse. The Logitech software should allow you to configure your mouse buttons. I've added details to the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Please let us know if your question is solved, by giving the answer a green check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The screenshot you are seeing is the Task switcher and it possibly being brought up because of a faulty touchpad or you have three fingers on (or very close to) the touch pad.

You might simply be using three fingers near the touchpad rather than a single finger and it is sensing all three.

[Touchpad gestures for Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4027871/windows-10-touchpad-gestures) includes the following gesture:

> **Switch between open windows:** Place three fingers on the touchpad and swipe right or left.

You can configure gestures, and potentially disable them, by going to Start  > Settings  > Devices > Touchpad.

You can find most of the options in there at [How to customize 'Precision Touchpad' settings on Windows 10](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-customize-precision-touchpad-settings-windows-10) and the specific gesture is this one:

[image]

---

Apparently the Logitech MX Master mice have a "gesture" button in the wing. It looks visible on the version 3 of the mouse, but [might be hidden in previous versions](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/How+to+fix+a+MX+Master+Permanently+active+Gestures/77985):

[image: https://uk.pcmag.com/computer-mice/122405/logitech-mx-master-3]

Image from [PCMag](https://uk.pcmag.com/computer-mice/122405/logitech-mx-master-3).

Apparently that button should be able to be configured using the [Logitech configuration software](https://support.logi.com/hc/en-gb/articles/360024154914).

Comment: It can also be a problem with palm rejection. resting the palm on the trackpad. Good call though, I did not think about this. :)

Comment: @LPChip apparently OPs mouse might also have a button for it... I've added that as another option.

Comment: Oh, that's also a good call.. I already gave you a +1. Can't give you another one... awww.... :D

Comment: @LPChip in all fairness it was you questioning in the comments that got the model of the mouse, I initially just assumed it was touchpad gestures because I actually *use* that specific gesture and was familiar with the behaviour. Logitech like putting extra button features on their mice so knowing it wasn't a generic mouse meant there could be something there so I had a dig. You deserve at least some credit for asking the right questions.

Comment: Thanks. :) Glad I could help. :)

Comment: Are the screenshots from Windows 2004 version?

Comment: @Valay_17 I doubt it, I see those option in 1909, and I'm sure they were there in 1903 and potentially earlier. If you don't have a "precision" (I.e. multitouch) touchpad then you might not have that functionality.

Comment: @Mokubai Pretty weird because I have a precision touchpad and use those gestures as well, but instead of the settings app, I have to go to the synaptics dialogue box and then select them.

Comment: I have no Synaptics software, it might be that it hides the precision side from Windows so it can handle it by the more specific drivers to avoid duplicating functionality. I dont know if uninstalling synaptics would make it appear at the location I mentioned, or if a clean install without might do it, I just know that's where I go these days.

Comment: @Mokubai Is it that you have the Windows Pro version because mine isn’t the Pro version maybe that might be the reason.

Comment: @Valay_17 not that either, I *do* have Pro, but it was upgraded from Home and I know that the options were there before I upgraded as I was using them for a few months before the upgrade. It has to be that you have dedicated software for it so the Windows options are disabled.

Comment: @Mokubai Thank You So Much for the information, in case it doesn’t work, I’ll create a question for the same as it wouldn’t be good to discuss this in the comments section.

Comment: @Mokubai I just returned to my PC and I see the question got a lot of responses and comments. Thank you to Mokubai for pinpointing the problem - my mouse has the hidden gesture button on the side (I did not even know there was a button there!). To test your theory, I lifted my mouse (so no moving or scrolling) and clicked the button with my thumb - sure enough I saw the same effect described in the OP! The button is either faulty or I might just need to configure it with Logitech software. BTW, I don't have touch on this PC so not related to that. Thanks to everyone for their feedback!